# Unable to load a Django model from a separate directory in a database script

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am having difficulty writing a python script that takes a directory of .txt files and loads them into my database that is utilized in a Django project.  Based on requirements the python script needs to be located in a separate directory than the api (my django directory).

Here is my project structure currently:

```
Main-Project/
  database/
    text-script.py
    text-files/
        example-file.txt
  django/
    django/
      settings.py
    snippets/
      models.py
```

My text-script.py file looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import django

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
sys.path.append(parent_dir)

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django.django.settings')
django.setup()

from django.snippets.models import Snippet

def import_articles(directory):
  for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endwith('.txt'):
      with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
        Snippet.objects.create(filename=filename, content=content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    text_dir = os.path.join(current_dir, 'text-files')
    import_articles(text_dir)
```

My installed apps looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'snippets.apps.SnippetsConfig',
]
```

I get this error when I try to run the script:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snippets'
```

How do I correctly load the Snippet model from my Django project to utilize the same database used in my Django project?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, of course right after finally posting the question!  I was setting my django root directory to the wrong directory.  I needed to set it to this

```
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)
root_dir = os.path.join(parent_dir, 'api')
sys.path.append(root_dir)
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Line responsible for the error is `from django.snippets.models import Snippet` .

Which should be as below.

```
from ..django.snippets.models import Snippet
```

You should use relative paths to import scripts inside your project.