# Problem in importing model files from same module

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Below is the pic of my Django Project structure.

[image]

I am trying to import model in data_models folder but it saying no module found. I have attached the pic for reference. Please guide me.

[image: [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2qum.png)]

I have tried many thing like removing it from main directory but still not working fine.

Comment: The \_\_init\_\_.py file is missing in the data_models directory. You should read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746675/how-to-write-a-python-module-package

Comment: I have __init__ file in data models directory. But still same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths. Not relative to project folder but to current script.

```
from ...AGDC.models import Product

#or

from ..models import Product
```

[Ref 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78157868/13861187)
[Ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78139751/13861187)